# How do you create inputs for a function that only has `args` in its parameters?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I'm attempting to use a library that's setup mainly to be used via the command line. I want to run its `main` function from within another Python file in order to programmatically create the inputs to the library.

The library code has a function I want to call, but the only input to it is `args`:

```py
def main(args):
    global counter
    set_global_variables(args)

    counter = 0
    # Loop through each line of the reference and hyp file
    for ref_line, hyp_line in zip(args.ref, args.hyp):
        processed_p = process_line_pair(ref_line, hyp_line, case_insensitive=args.case_insensitive,
                                        remove_empty_refs=args.remove_empty_refs)
    
    # removed irrelevant computational code
    # removed irrelevant output code

# dropping this in for reference since it's the list of variables args can have
def set_global_variables(args):
    """Copy argparse args into global variables."""
    global print_instances_p
    global print_errors_p
    global files_head_ids
    global files_tail_ids
    global confusions
    global min_count
    global wer_vs_length_p
    # Put the command line options into global variables.
    print_instances_p = args.print_instances
    print_errors_p = args.print_errors
    files_head_ids = args.head_ids
    files_tail_ids = args.tail_ids
    confusions = args.confusions
    min_count = args.min_word_count
    wer_vs_length_p = args.print_wer_vs_length
```

The repo says the command line usage for the project is:

```
usage: wer [-h] [-i | -r] [--head-ids] [-id] [-c] [-p] [-m count] [-a] [-e]
           ref hyp
```

How do I create the input parameter for this `main(args)` function?

---

I tried this but it did not work:

```py
ref = "some/file/in/my/system.txt"
hyp = "some/different/file/in/my/system.txt"
library.main({reference_transcript, hypothesis_transcript, 'case_insensitive': True})
# Syntax error: invalid syntax                                          here ^
# IDE Says: "An illegal target for a variable annotation"
```

The following worked, but is it the most Pythonic way to do it? The problem with it is that it requires knowing exactly what the target library uses for the variable/key names within `args` which requires access to the library code. Also I wouldn't be able to use the flags specified by the library as flags (e.g. passing in `-c`).

```py
ref = "some/file/in/my/system.txt"
hyp = "some/different/file/in/my/system.txt"
args = {'ref': ref, 'hyp': hyp, 'case_insensitive': True, 'remove_empty_refs': True}
asr_evaluation.main(args)
```

I know that I could probably call the library using `subprocess.run` but I'd rather directly call the library within Python since it is a Python library.

---

Editing to add:
The library uses a wrapper `__main__.py` file to actually run the main function I copied above:

```py
def main():
    """Run the program."""
    parser = get_parser()
    args = parser.parse_args()
    other_main(args)

def get_parser():
    """Parse the CLI args."""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Evaluate an ASR transcript against a reference transcript.')
    parser.add_argument('ref', type=argparse.FileType('r'), help='Reference transcript filename')
    parser.add_argument('hyp', type=argparse.FileType('r'), help='ASR hypothesis filename')
    print_args = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    print_args.add_argument('-i', '--print-instances', action='store_true',
                            help='Print all individual sentences and their errors.')
    print_args.add_argument('-r', '--print-errors', action='store_true',
                            help='Print all individual sentences that contain errors.')
    parser.add_argument('--head-ids', action='store_true',
                        help='Hypothesis and reference files have ids in the first token? (Kaldi format)')
    parser.add_argument('-id', '--tail-ids', '--has-ids', action='store_true',
                        help='Hypothesis and reference files have ids in the last token? (Sphinx format)')
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--confusions', action='store_true', help='Print tables of which words were confused.')
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--print-wer-vs-length', action='store_true',
                        help='Print table of average WER grouped by reference sentence length.')
    parser.add_argument('-m', '--min-word-count', type=int, default=1, metavar='count',
                        help='Minimum word count to show a word in confusions (default 1).')
    parser.add_argument('-a', '--case-insensitive', action='store_true',
                        help='Down-case the text before running the evaluation.')
    parser.add_argument('-e', '--remove-empty-refs', action='store_true',
                        help='Skip over any examples where the reference is empty.')

    return parser
```

However even if I run the main function in the wrapper file, my question still stands: **How do I create command line arguments within Python and pass them into a library that is set up to only run from command line?**

Comment: `args` is supposed to be a class object. The class has attributes like `ref`, `case_insensitive`, etc.

Comment: `args` as produced by `parse_args` is an `argparse.Namespace` object, https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-namespace-object.  This is a relatively simple class, that has attributes.  Use `print(args)` to see what it looks like.  Your `parser` will produce one with attributes like `args.ref`, `args.min_word_count`, etc.  `vars(args)` produces an equivalent `dict`.

Comment: You can create an equivalent object with `args = argparse.Namespace(ref='foo', min_wor_count=3, ...)` syntax